# Template feature not saving and win explorer not visible

Tags: site, template

This may have been asked before but I am using SharePoint 2010, and am retiring a site.  A certain list is too large to make as a template and the windows explorer is not visible under my ribbon > list view.  Any alternatives to copying the data out and saving elsewhere?  I want to keep the list as is and not export into excel. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 2 options: Powershell or through Central Admin console. Details here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428293(v=office.14).aspx